# if statement not working in Django template

Tags: python, django, django-templates

The `if` statement within the `for` loop of the template is not working. It is still showing unavailable items.
This is the code of my template

### form-template.html

```
{% for field in form %}
{% if eventprojector.projector.available %}
    <div class="form-group">
    <div class="col-sm-offset-2 col-sm-10">
    <span class="text-danger small">{{ field.errors }} </span>
    </div>
    <label class="control-label col-sm-2">{{ field.label_tag }} </label>
    <div class ="col-sm-10">{{ field }} </div>
    </div>
{%endif %}
{% endfor %}
```

Comment: you should test this template standalone (outside of django); try to render it using [jinja](http://jinja.pocoo.org/). if you still run into problems, please post the input data you want to render along with the template. otherwise people here can hardly help...

Comment: Try replacing `{%endif %}` with `{% endif %}`, notice the prefixed space.

Comment: is the variable `eventprojector.projector.available` is `boolean` in your views?

Comment: yes..It is a boolean field @Tiny.D

Comment: still not working @nik_m

Comment: Why you don't move if outside for loop. because "eventprojector.projector.available" doesn't depend on field and is constant!

Comment: I tried but not working. @mohammad

Comment: can you please share your views? I wanna test and repeat your code.

Comment: What I need is hiding those projectors which are unavailable.Views are working well.But not able to do with the template @Tiny.D

Answer (score 1):

Here is the refactoring code which will work for both available and unavailable items based on your code:

**event/models.py:**

```
from django.db import models

# Create your models here.
class Projectors(models.Model):
    pro = models.CharField(max_length=50)
    available = models.BooleanField(default=True)
    def __str__(self):
        return self.pro

class Eventprojector(models.Model):
    projector = models.ForeignKey(Projectors)
    date = models.DateField(blank=True, null=True)
    start = models.CharField(max_length=50, null=True)
    end = models.CharField(max_length=50, null=True)
    is_accept = models.IntegerField(default=0)

    def get_absolute_url(self):
        return reverse( 'retest:eventprojectorform')
    def __str__(self):
        return str(self.id)
```

**event/urls.py:**

```
from django.conf.urls import url

from . import views

urlpatterns = [
    # ex: /event/1/
    url(r'^(?P<eventprojector_id>[0-9]+)/$', views.projectoraccept, name='projectoraccept'),
]
```

**event/views.py:**

```
from django.shortcuts import render, get_object_or_404
from .models import Eventprojector
# Create your views here.

def projectoraccept(request, eventprojector_id):
    eventprojector = get_object_or_404(Eventprojector, pk=eventprojector_id)
    eventprojector.is_accept = eventprojector.is_accept+1
    eventprojector.save(update_fields=['is_accept'])
    if eventprojector.is_accept == 3:
        eventprojector.projector.available = False
        eventprojector.projector.save(update_fields=['available'])
    return render(request, 'event/projectordetails.html' , {'eventprojector' : eventprojector })
```

**statckoverflow/urls.py:**

```
from django.conf.urls import url, include
from django.contrib import admin

urlpatterns = [
    url(r'^event/', include('event.urls')),
    url(r'^admin/', admin.site.urls),
]
```

**stackoverflow/event/templates/event/projectordetails.html:**

```
{% if eventprojector.projector.available %}
    <div class="form-group">
    <div class="col-sm-offset-2 col-sm-10">
    <span class="text-danger small">TEST</span>
    </div>
    <label class="control-label col-sm-2">TESTTEST</label>
    <div class ="col-sm-10">TESTETST</div>
    </div>
{% endif %}
```

After all environment is setting, add some test data into tables through admin console:

```
event_projectors: pro = 'TEST1' and available= True
event_eventprojector :  projector = 'TEST1' date = today, start = 1, end = 2, is_accept = 1
```

Then run server to start to test:

1, When you first time type in `http://127.0.0.1:8000/event/1/`, it will show the form like this: (here 'is_accept' field in eventprojector will plus 1 to be 2, check view function)

```
<div class="form-group">
<div class="col-sm-offset-2 col-sm-10">
<span class="text-danger small">TEST</span>
</div>
<label class="control-label col-sm-2">TESTTEST</label>
<div class ="col-sm-10">TESTETST</div>
</div>
```

2,  When you enter again the url `http://127.0.0.1:8000/event/1/`, 'is_accept' field in eventprojector will plus 1 again to be 3, and then it will set `eventprojector.projector.available = False`, here you cannot see the the element, it is empty in template.

Hope above code can help you to render template projectordetails.html with the parameters eventprojector correctly, note that the render function `render(request, 'event/projectordetails.html' , {'eventprojector' : eventprojector })` will only render to tempalte `event/projectordetails.html` with parameter `eventprojector`. Probably, there is some mismatch in your template?

Answer (score 0):

models.py

```
class Projectors(models.Model):
pro = models.CharField(max_length=50)
sec = models.ForeignKey(Section)
available = models.BooleanField(default=True)
def __str__(self):
             return self.pro 
class Eventprojector(models.Model):
projector = models.ForeignKey(Projectors)
date = models.DateField(blank=True, null=True)
start = models.CharField(max_length=50, null=True)
end = models.CharField(max_length=50, null=True)
is_accept = models.IntegerField(default=0)

def get_absolute_url(self):
    return reverse( 'retest:eventprojectorform')
def __str__(self):
             return str(self.id)
```

views.py

```
def projectoraccept(request, eventprojector_id):
eventprojector = get_object_or_404(Eventprojector, pk=eventprojector_id)
if request.method == 'POST':
    eventprojector.is_accept = eventprojector.is_accept+1
    eventprojector.save(update_fields=['is_accept'])
        if eventprojector.is_accept == 3:
            if eventprojector.projector.sec.sec_name == 'CS_dept':
                eventprojector.projector.available = False
                eventprojector.projector.save(update_fields=['available'])
            elif eventprojector.projector.sec.sec_name == 'EC_dept':
                eventprojector.projector.available = False
                eventprojector.projector.save(update_fields=['available'])
            elif eventprojector.projector.sec.sec_name == 'EEE_dept':
                 eventprojector.projector.available = False
                 eventprojector.projector.save(update_fields=['available'])
            elif eventprojector.projector.sec.sec_name == 'IEEE':
                 eventprojector.projector.available = False
                eventprojector.projector.save(update_fields=['available'])
            elif eventprojector.projector.sec.sec_name == 'TCP_dept':
                 eventprojector.projector.available = False
                 eventprojector.projector.save(update_fields=['available'])
return render(request, 'event/projectordetails.html' , {'eventprojector' : eventprojector })
```